# Cannot get data from an Node API

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an API (Localhost:3000) using node and a front end (Localhost:4200) using Angular 6. Using my regular chrome browser, I am able to CRUD to the database in the API but when I use the android emulator using (10.0.2.2:4200), I cannot do any of the CRUD to the database anymore. Please see my codes below:

**Node [index.js]**

```
const express   = require("express");
const nedb      = require("nedb");
const rest      = require("express-nedb-rest");
const cors      = require("cors");

const app = express();

const datastore = new nedb({
    filename: "mycoffeeapp.db",
    autoload: true
});

const restAPI = rest();
restAPI.addDatastore('coffees', datastore);

app.use(cors());
app.use('/', restAPI);

app.listen(3000);
```

**angular front end**
This is in the data.service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class DataService {
  public endpoint = "http://localhost:3000";


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  getList(callback) {
    this.http.get(`${this.endpoint}/coffees`)
      .subscribe(response => {
        callback(response);
      });
  }

  get(coffeeId: string, callback) {
    this.http.get(`${this.endpoint}/coffees/${coffeeId}`)
      .subscribe(response => {
        callback(response);
      });
  }

  save(coffee, callback) {
    if (coffee._id) {
      this.http.put(`${this.endpoint}/coffees/${coffee._id}`, coffee)
        .subscribe(response => {
          callback(true);
        });
    } else {
      this.http.post(`${this.endpoint}/coffees`, coffee)
      .subscribe(response => {
        callback(true);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

in the component:

```
constructor(
    private data: DataService,
    private router: Router,
    private gls: GeoLocationService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getList(list => {
      this.list = list;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow entirely. Are you running the angular front-end on an emulated android device in the chrome browser?

Comment: Your post is missing a question. Can you also add the observed behavior, any errors ? Missing values ?

Comment: You probably need to specify an IP address for the API, instead of `"http://localhost:3000"`, e.g. `http://10.0.2.2:3000`

Comment: can you post the errors that are visible in the console of browser ?

Comment: @ErwinLengkeek No Sir. I am running the emulator from android studio.

Comment: @ibenjelloun: I do not get any errors when I use the chrome browser. If I use the chorome in an emulated android device from android studio, I cannot get the errors since I cannot use the inspect element.

Comment: I don't have any errors in my desktop chrome browser and it runs perfectly. My issue is when it is running on the chrome browser of the emulated device.

Comment: @David: should I place the http://localhost:3000 on my front end or in the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run an emulated android device and try to access your development environment environment on  `10.0.2.2:4200`, you'll be able to reach the angular app provided that th emulator is on the same network.

Now, you need to make sure that your API is reachable from outside of your local machine, and, in your angular front, set the API url using an IP address

```
export class DataService {
  public endpoint = "http://10.0.2.2:3000";
```

If you use `localhost`, this will point to the emulated device itself, which does not have you API runnnig

Comment: If I use the "http://10.0.2.2:3000", on my desktop browser, I cannot get the data from the node server anymore. But I can see it now in the android emulator.

Comment: Is there a way I can see this on both the desktop browser and android emulated browser?

Comment: @Ibanez1408 This should from work your desktop browser as well. Unless you've got some proxy settings  preventing you from doing that

Comment: I'm not using any proxy Sir. I just couldn't get the desktop browser to work with the 10. series. But if I use the localhost or 127.0.0.1, my desktop browser works but not the android.

Comment: This is the error I get in the inspection "GET http://10.0.2.2:3000/coffees net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Comment: @Ibanez1408: maybe open a different question. Apart from some proxy settings, I don't know what could cause that.

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you for the help.